# OmnisSci: "Sorting the result would be too slow"

Tags: omniscidb, pymapd

I  am using OmniSci with pymapd to get ~5M rows of data.

Running a select with

```
SELECT a, b ,c, d
FROM my_table
ORDER BY a, b
```

Fails with the following database error:

```
Sorting the result would be too slow
```

For this query, I really don't care it would be slow.

Can I make this work on OmniSci (even slowly), or should I leave sorting to pandas/etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can run this query disabling the watchdog that's blocking you, so if You have an omnisci.conf file you have just to add `enable-watchdog=false` to it;
if you are running the omnisci_server from the command line, to start the server, append `--enable-watchdog=false`.

Said that the omnisci database is extremely fast filtering, aggregating, and joining large volumes of data, but it's not so fast projecting and/or sorting medium or large volume of data, because the operations are serialized right now; of course, we are working to improve those aspects.